# Warning message: By Converting Dates to Numeric Values

Tags: r

```
date_to_numeric<- function(x)#function for construction of date
{  
  strptime(x,format = "%Y-%m-%d")->t
  if(is.na(t)==TRUE)
    strptime(x,format = "%Y%m%d")->t
  as.numeric(format(t, "%Y"))->t1
  as.numeric(format(t, "%m"))->t2
  as.numeric(format(t, "%d"))->t3

  d<-c(0,0.08493150685,0.1616438356,0.2465753425,0.3287671233,0.4136986301,0.495890411,0.5808219178,0.6657534247,0.7479452055,0.8328767123,0.9150684932)
  d[t2]->t2
  t3<-t3/365
  result<-t1+t2+t3
  return(result)
}

time(d)->t
t<-date_to_numeric(t)

Warning message:
In if (is.na(t) == TRUE) t <- strptime(x, format = "%yyyy%mm%dd") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can please someone explain to me why I get this error message ? I usde the same Code in jannuary last year and it woked fine ! Any hepel is hilgly preciated !

Comment: don't use `if`, use `ifelse` which is Vectorized. The warning is telling you that you need to loop your `if` statement to get all elements not only the first...

Comment: so insteed of using   if(is.na(t)==TRUE)  i should use   ifelse(is.na(t)==TRUE)

Comment: The syntax is `ifelse(is.na(t), ..., ...)` FYI, `is.na(t)` evaluates to logical so no need for you to add the `==TRUE` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sotos mentioned, the reason you are receiving this warning message is because in your function, you are using and `if` statement but object `t` is likely a vector of dates. Since `if` is not vectorized, your function will only check if the first element of `t` is missing (in `if (is.na(t))`), and it is giving you this precise warning. Note that your code will still run, however it probably won't return what you are expecting.

The simplest way to fix this without editing your function is using `sapply()`. You can do something like this:

```
t <- time(d)
t2 <- sapply(t, FUN = date_to_numeric)
```

You can also edit your `date_to_numeric` function to allow for proper vectorized calculations, which I would recommend for the long run.

Comment: thank you dwhdai  :-) ..sapply(...) works fine ! in case I Need to Change the function how can i do that ?

Comment: I would try changing the line containing `if(is.na(t))` to this:

`t <- ifelse(is.na(t), strptime(x,format = "%Y%m%d"), t)`